# Why are some maps cofibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am currently reading a textbook in which it is claimed that both the following maps are (Hurewitz) cofibrations $A\vee A\rightarrow A\wedge (I_+)$ (the first $A$ is mapped to $A\times\{0\}$ and the second to $A\times\{1\}$) and $A\rightarrow CA$, where $CA$ is the reduced cone on $A$, and $A$ is a non-degenerately based space.

I have thought about showing that these subspaces are NDR using the DR of $A\wedge (I_+)$ to $A$, but my attempts have not been successful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some knowledge about cofibrations. I don't know which book you use, but most authors focus on *closed cofibrations*. These are cofibrations $i : A \to X$ such that $i(A)$  is closed in $X$. Also NDR pairs $(X,A)$ are usually only defined for closed $A \subset X$. The definition of NDR pairs can be generalized to arbitrary $A \subset X$, but we do not consider this here.

We need the following facts about cofibrations.

(1) Let $i : A \to X$, $f : A \to B$, $i' : B \to Y$ and $f' : X \to Y$ be four maps which form a pushout diagram. If $i$ is cofibration, then also $i'$ is a cofibration.

(2) An inclusion $i : A \to X$ of a closed subspace is a cofibration if and only if $(X,A)$ is a NDR pair.

(3) If $(X,A), (Y,B)$ are NDR pairs, then so is $(X \times Y, X \times B \cup A \times Y)$.

$A$ has a non-degenerate basepoint $a_0$ which means that $(A, \{ a_0 \})$ is  an NDR pair.

$A \vee A$ is obtained from the disjoint union of two copies of $A$ by identifying the two copies of $a_0$. An equivalent representation is
$$A \vee A = (A \times \{ 0, 1\} \cup \{ a_0 \} \times I) / \{ a_0 \} \times I .$$
Let $p : A \times \{ 0, 1\} \cup \{ a_0 \} \times I \to A \vee A$ denote the quotient map.

$A \wedge I_+$ is nothing else than $A \times I / \{ a_0 \} \times I$. Let $p' : A \times I \to A \times I / \{ a_0 \} \times I$ denote the quotient map. Its restriction $p''$ to $A \times \{ 0, 1\} \cup \{ a_0 \} \times I$ induces a unique map $i' : A \vee A \to A \times I / \{ a_0 \} \times I$ such that $i' \circ p = p'' = p' \circ i$ where $i : A \times \{ 0, 1\} \cup \{ a_0 \} \times I \to A \times I$ denotes the inclusion map. Obviously $A_k  = p(A \times \{ k \}) \subset A \vee A$ is mapped by $i'$ homeomorphically onto $A'_k = p'(A \times \{ k \}) \subset  A \times I / \{ a_0 \} \times I$.

It is an easy exercise to verify that the four maps $i, p, i', p'$ form a pushout diagram.

By (3) $(A \times I, A \times \{ 0, 1\} \cup \{ a_0 \} \times I)$ is an NDR pair. Therefore $i$ is a cofibration and (1) shows that also $i'$ is one.

The reduced cone $CA$ can be represented as

$$CA = (A \times I / \{ a_0 \} \times I) / A'_1 .$$

Let $r' : A \times I / \{ a_0 \} \times I \to CA$ denote the quotient map. The map $i'' : A \to CA, i''(x) = r'(p'(x,0))$, is the canonical embedding of $A$ as the base of $CA$.

The map $R : A \times \{ 0, 1\} \cup \{ a_0 \} \times I \to A, R(x,t) = x$ for $t = 0$, $R(x,t) = a_0$ for $t > 0$, induces a unique map $r : A \vee A \to A$ such that $R = r \circ p$. It is the identity on $A_0$ and contracts $A_1$ to $a_0$.

Again it is an easy exercise to verify that the four maps $i', r, i'', r'$ form a pushout diagram. This implies that $i''$ is a cofibration since $i'$ is one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Btw, the book I'm reading works in CGWH, so cofibrations are always closed inclusions.